# Adding UltraCombo to Already Formatted ToolStrip

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics, toolstrip, ultracombo

I am trying to change the combo box in this image to an ultra combo control (this is a picture of a tool strip with controls added):

[image]

In my view's constructor, I've added the following:

```
UltraCombo cboArea2 = new UltraCombo();
ToolStripControlHost tsHost = new ToolStripControlHost(cboArea2);

tsMain.Items.Clear();

tsMain.Items.Add(toolStripLabel2);
tsMain.Items.Add(toolStripLabel1);
tsMain.Items.Add(tsHost);
tsMain.Items.Add(toolStripSeparator1);
tsMain.Items.Add(btnGetArea);
tsMain.Items.Add(btnCreateArea);
```

However, this causes the following to happen:

[image]

I'm not sure why the combo box and buttons are being added into a dropdown instead of the toolstrip.

Can anybody provide feedback as to how to format this the way I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, I realize this is a known issue, with no known (that I could find) fixes:
http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/79785.aspx

I had to do some "hacky" things to get around this... I literally had to create an open space on the ToolStrip with a disabled ComboBox, then, using the arrow keys (can't actually drag and drop UltraCombos onto the toolstrip), position the UltraCombo on top of the ComboBox. Now it looks like I want it to, though I wouldn't call this an actual fix.